# .htaccess: redirect common forms of index url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, web, redirect

I want to redirect all common forms of an index url.

My .htaccess file looks like this right now:

```
## Mod_rewrite in use.
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect .html URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

With my knowledge I created this expression:

```
## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect index
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)index(\.php|\.html?)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [R=301,L]

# Redirect .html URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

And it doesn't work.

This are my questions:

1. Why can't I use the NC flag there?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.html$ [NC]
```

2. When I use RewriteRule in combination with RewriteCond, what is RewriteRule selecting.

```
Sample URL: https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/
```

This is the condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.html$
```

In my use case is regex selecting the part between string start and .html. But whats the string start?

3. Why is my first Condition & Rule not working?

I want to select all this urls:

```
.com/index.html
.com/index.htm
.com/index.php
.com/index
```

Thx for the support.

Comment: `Why can't I use the NC flag there?` You can use `NC` there and it's working as expected but the problem is with your other two conditions `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` these conditions prevent your existent `.html` files from the redirection.

Comment: Please explain it to me more detailed, I don't check it. Why is the NC preventing it?

Comment: "Why is the NC preventing it?" - It's not preventing anything. What makes you think it is?

Comment: You need to describe in natural language exactly what you are trying to do. Your initial directives that remove the `.html` extension from URLs where the request does **not** map to a file are "OK" - but is that really what you want to do? Are you suggesting that your first rule (at the top of your question) is working as intended? But how are these URLs then being routed? This rule does not make much sense by itself?